# Does the Bestow Curse spell's extra damage apply to the Dragon's Breath spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, stacking

The [*bestow curse*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bestow-curse) spell states:

> [...] While the target is cursed, your attacks and spells deal an extra 1d8 necrotic damage to the target. [...]

I'm wondering how this interacts with the [*dragon's breath*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dragons-breath) spell (XGtE, p. 154), which grants a creature you touch a new action to create a damage-dealing area of effect. Does this count as your spell dealing damage and thus activate *bestow curse*? If not, does this change if *dragon's breath* was originally cast on yourself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes

*Dragon's Breath* is your spell, regardless of what creature you cast it on. It should benefit from *Bestow Curse* for the same reason it uses your spell save DC; It's still damage from your spell, just with extra steps.