# Does the Bestow Curse spell add 1d8 necrotic damage to spells that normally do not deal damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage

The fourth option for the spell [*bestow curse*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bestow-curse) (PHB, pg. 218) reads:

> - While the target is cursed, your attacks and spells deal an extra 1d8 necrotic damage to the target.

Does this extra 1d8 damage occur when one of my non-damaging spells affects the cursed creature?

Comment: Related: "[Can other damage (from class abilities/feats) be added to net attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86353)"

Comment: Related: [Does the Bestow Curse spell's extra damage apply to the Dragon's Breath spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/170056/does-the-bestow-curse-spells-extra-damage-apply-to-the-dragons-breath-spell)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### You cannot deal *extra* damage if you did not deal damage in the first place

#### Quotes from a pre-existing similar question

- [Can other damage (from class abilities/feats) be added to net attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86353)

The Sharpshooter feat and Sneak Attack features (the examples in the question just linked) state the following (emphasis mine):

> [...] If the attack hits, you add +10 to **the attack’s damage.** [...]

> [...] you can deal an **extra** 1d6 damage [...]

---

From [Miniman's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/86362) (the highest scoring one):

> [...] So why won't this [using the Sharpshooter feat to add damage] work with nets? Because you add +10 to the attack's damage. However, an attack with a net doesn't deal damage in the first place, so there's nothing to add damage to. It's not a case of 0 + 10 = 10; a net lists "-" as its damage, not 0.
>
> [...]
>
> [Sneak Attack does] 1d6 extra damage. For there to be extra damage, there has to be damage. Since there's no damage to begin with, you can't have extra damage. [...]

---

From [KorvinStarmast's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/86360) (second highest score):

> [...] The reason you can't add damage to the net from Sharpshooter (or other feat) is that a net doesn't do damage in the first place.
>
> [...]
>
> Put in a more mechanistic way: as there is no damage entry per the weapons table, there is nothing to add +10 to. [...]

---

#### How does this extend to *bestow curse*?

These both conclude that you cannot add damage or apply *extra* damage to things that do not ordinarily deal damage. Continuing with this knowledge we see that the *bestow curse* spell states (emphasis mine):

> [...] your attacks and spells deal an **extra** 1d8 necrotic damage [...]

Since this is similarly *extra* damage I would similarly conclude that you cannot add it to something that does not deal any damage to begin with.

---

<sup>For what it's worth, the Lead Rules Designer Jeremy Crawford has said the following in [a tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/586414191495393282):</sup>

> <sup>The intent is that a net doesn't deal extra damage because it's not dealing damage in the first place.</sup>

<sup>Of course, that is simply how he felt at the time he posted it, and we can't really know *why* he felt that way, but if you want to know how he felt, you've got an answer.</sup>